# Javascript - OnMouseOut Event not work for the first li element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event in my project.

The event works but I have a problem, and I can´t understand why it is happening.

I have several `<li>` elements and I can change the image when I do `mousehover` and `onmouseout` change to the original image.

But with the first `<li>` element, on the `onmouseout` event, it's not fired, only on the `onmousehover` event.

I have test it with an alert box, and it words for all, except the first one doesn´t.

Any idea what happening?

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code.**

```
@{x=0;}

<ul>
         @foreach (var p in ViewBag.In)
          {                                 
              <li>             
                  <form action="" method="post">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit"
                          onmouseover="document.getElementById('@("icon" + x.ToString())').src = '@p.IconHover';"
                          onmouseout="document.getElementById('@("icon" + x.ToString())').src = '@p.Icon';">

                         <img src="@p.Icon" id="@("icon" + x.ToString())"/>

                      </button>

                 </form>
              </li>
              x = x + 1;
          } 
    </ul>
```

**I think i know where the problem:**

```
document.getElementById('icon0').src=' /Content/Images_BD/Icons/Interaction/appbar.logo.png';
```

only the line have a space in the src.

the other li elements dont have the space in source path.. how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you really using jQuery?

Comment: i have jquery libraries but i think it have nothing to do with it.


this is only javascript

this is working for all, but only for the first li element the mouseout event its not fired

Comment: Can you provide the pure HTML output?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @reporter:  i have update my code... take a look pls

Comment: Those newlines probably aren't helping - I'd look into cleaning those path inputs before outputting if I were you

Comment: Are sure that your example does not work? Based on your added html it works, see http://jsfiddle.net/AywhC/ , even in IE7 mode.

Comment: @all... i think the problem is in the path of the first li element, because it begins with a space, the other don´t do that...

Comment: Yes, look at the array you are using to fill the list.  The Icon property of the first element of ViewBag.In likely starts with `" /Content"` (With a space before the `"/"`) Can you show us where `ViewBag.In` is defined?

Comment: ok.. im a little bit frustrated now..

i have found the solution for this issue.

in my database i had the src path with a space at the begining. 

i have look to it a lots of time and only now i have see the damn space..



thanks to everyone for helping me..